# Does Netflix work on Google Chrome

Tags: system-installation, netflix

I am about to download Ubuntu 15.04 and I am a new user. Before I download and install I want to confirm if I would be able to download chrome on this version and if I can watch Netflix on it.

Furthermore, do I need to download any sort of flash player with chrome or would it just play all the videos from various websites?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10. I installed Chrome from the [Google download page](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html) and Netflix works just fine. I installed the Chromecast plugin in the browser and I can even use it with my Chromecast. Very happy with it!